# can't release thread in opengles on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, egl

I have some problem..

When call the function, eglReleaseThread(), immediately application is closed   without any return value on specific device which is 'Galaxy S4'.
 other devices (galaxy note2,3 galaxy S7) don't make the error.
I use JNI for openGLES 2.0 and the specific device has 4.3 version (API 18)

This is release Part source code.

```
if (mEGLDisplay != EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
    CppLog("env - release - exist display");
    if(!eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT)){
        CppError("ImageProcGLES - eglMakeCurrent");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        CppLog("env - release - eglMakeCurrent");
    }

    if(!eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface)){
        CppError("ImageProcGLES - eglDestroySurface Error.");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        CppLog("env - release - eglDestroySurface");
    }

    if(!eglDestroyContext(mEGLDisplay, mEGLContext)){
        CppError("ImageProcGLES - eglDestroyContext.");
        return -1;
    }else{
        CppLog("env - release - eglDestroyContext");
    }

    if(!eglReleaseThread()){
        CppError("ImageProcGLES - eglReleaseThread.");
        return -1;
    }else{
        CppLog("env - release - eglReleaseThread");
    }

    if(!eglTerminate(mEGLDisplay)){
        CppError("ImageProcGLES - eglTerminate.");
        return -1;
    }else{
        CppLog("env - release - eglTerminate");
    }
}
else{
    CppError("env - release - No Display");
}
```

and this is return log.

```
    buffer - release
    env - release - start
    env - release - exist display
    env - release - eglMakeCurrent
    env - release - eglDestroySurface
    env - release - eglDestroyContext
```

If you have some idea... please help me :(

Comment: Looks like a bug in the device driver. Which specific model of the Galaxy S4 are you using? Some are based on SGX GPUs, others are based on Adreno GPUs.

Comment: @solidpixel if it is bug in device drive, how to fix the problem?
I don't know exactly which gpu is used, perhaps it is **I9500/South Korea model** that is based on 'SGX544MP3' GPU

Comment: You can't fix it. Workaround it perhaps, but not fix it. Best answer is probably just avoid calling `eglReleaseThread()` ... in theory all EGL resources should be freed when you call `eglTerminate()` anyway ..

Comment: Ah..! You mean it doesn't make the problem if i didn't call the `eglReleaseThrede()`, Because `eglTerminate()` free all resource such as memory, thread and so on... Doesn't it really make the problem if Init and release are repeated? I worry about that App will be dead coz' many thread is made

Comment: No - there shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: It is bug in egl diver whitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in EGL driver. I used to have the same issue, to work around it create egl surface from Surface and not SurfaceTexture.
When you create surface:

```
mSurface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
             mEglSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEglDisplay, 
mEglConfig, mSurface, surfaceAttribs, 0);
```

Key moment here is to create Surface from SurfaceTexture:

```
Surface surface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
```